# Is $\{ n\in \mathbb N:x_n\in U\}\notin I\iff\{n\in \mathbb N:x_n\notin U\}\in I $ true?

Tags: general-topology, ideals

$I$ is an ideal of $\mathbb N$ i.e. a collection of subsets of $\mathbb N$ satisfying

1. $\varnothing\in I$
2. $A\in I, B\subset A \implies B\in I$
3. $A,B\in I \implies A\cup B \in I$

$\{x_n\}_n$ is a sequence of elements of a topological space $X$ and $y$ is fixed point in $X$. Then $y$ is called ***$I$-cluster point*** of $\{x_n\}$ if for every open nbd of $y$ $\{n\in \mathbb N: x_n\in U\}\notin I.$ This is the given definition in [this paper](http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0166864112001812/1-s2.0-S0166864112001812-main.pdf?_tid=9478c71e-8bd5-11e6-b105-00000aacb35f&acdnat=1475766191_f0e301f1a5b8253503569088e8eb7b25) **pg no 2622,Definition $1$.**

Now my question is , can I say 
$\{ n\in \mathbb N:x_n\in U\}\notin I\iff\{n\in \mathbb N:x_n\notin U\}\in I  \ ?$ That'll rephrase the definition as  $y$ is called ***$I$-cluster point*** of $\{x_n\}$ if for every open nbd of $y$ $\{n\in \mathbb N: x_n\notin U\}\in I.$

Thank you.

Comment: I assumed that by $\Phi$ you meant the empty set. It's better to use `\emptyset` or `\varnothing`. If I was mistaken, please edit it back.

Comment: Yes . thank you. @Arthur

Comment: In the light of condition 2, condition 1 can be replaced with $I\ne\emptyset$

Comment: It’s true if and only if $I$ is a maximal ideal.

Comment: What you wrote in the title is not true. But a useful condition which is equivalent characterization of $I$-cluster points is that for every $M\in F(I)$ we have $\{n; x_n\in U\}\cap M\ne\emptyset$. (Where $F(I)$ denotes the filter dual to $I$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. Unless you have reason to believe that $A\notin I\iff (\Bbb N\setminus A)\in I$